# Get the record count using dirpagination

Tags: angularjs, dirpagination

Using dir-pagination, is there a way to get the total number of records?  I looked over the documentation and through stackoverflow but didn't have any luck.

```
<div dir-paginate="provider in vm.providers | filter:vm.gender | itemsPerPage:3">
 ...
</div

// the page control
<dir-pagination-controls max-size="5"
                         direction-links="true"
                         boundary-links="true">
</dir-pagination-controls>
```

Comment: Could you show us some code, you probably can get the count in the scope variable ou use as parameter

Comment: @DMCISSOKHO  I tried that but vm.providers.length doesn't get updated after I apply my filter but the pagination still works.